# Postman Tests: Assert several possible response statuses

Tags: testing, postman

When testing in Postman, you can use `pm.response.to.have.status(200)` to assert that the response status should be 200.

Is there any simple way to assert multiple statuses? I tried `pm.response.to.have.status(200||404)` and it didn't work.

I'm looking at the [Postman Sandbox API Reference](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference) and there doesn't seem to be a straightforward solution for this, although maybe something can be worked out.

Since it's rather bizarre, I'll explain why I want this: it's a DELETE request that will standardize the database for later requests and I don't care which is returned as long as it's either 200 or 404.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

([It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))

Found an example in the [test examples](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples):

```
pm.test("Successful POST request", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([201,202]);
});
```

in my case, it would be something like

```
pm.test("Previous DELETE request", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([200,404]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just to add to the approved response, you can add a return statement like this:

```
pm.test("Previous DELETE request", function () {
 const expectedStatusCodes = [200,404];
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf(expectedStatusCodes,
           `did not expect response status to be one of ${expectedStatusCodes} but got ${pm.response.code}.`
    );
});
```